# t1way producing NAs in output

Tags: r

I'm attempting to use the robust ANOVA method `t1way` from the `WRS2` package.

One issue is that I keep getting an output that has `NA` in it. It looks like this:

```
Test statistic: NA 
Degrees of Freedom 1: 17 
Degrees of Freedom 2: NA 
p-value: NA
```

I'm not certain why this is happening. The data set is very large and contains multiple groups. There are some `NA` but `t1way` seems to be able to handle `NA` when I have tried to simulate some data and run the test. Additionally, when I try and go to the post hoc testing (just because I wanted see what would happen), using the `lincon()` function, it gives me an error saying I have duplicate row names. This error doesn't make sense to me as each group is represented multiple times. There error I keep getting states this:

> Error in data.frame(psihat = c(" 0.73800", " 0.43766", " 0.14644", " 0.43915", : duplicate row.names: OG vs. NA, DT vs. NA, OT vs. NA, C vs. NA, QB vs. NA, OLB vs. NA, DE vs. NA, TE vs. NA, RB vs. NA, WR vs. NA, ILB vs. NA, FB vs. NA, CB vs. NA, FS vs. NA, SS vs. NA, NA vs. NA In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

I have simulated an example of the format of my data, albeit much smaller, and it seems to work fine:

```
set.seed(333)
Score1 <- rnorm(n = 50, mean = 25, sd = 12)
Score2 <- rnorm(n = 50, mean = 32, sd = 6)
Score3 <- rnorm(n = 20, mean = 10, sd = 8)
Score <- c(Score1, Score2, Score3)
Group <- rep(c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3"), c(50,50,20))
df <- data.frame(Group, Score)
df

library(WRS2)

t1way(Score ~ Group, data = df, tr = 0.2)
lincon(Score ~ Group, data = df, tr = 0.2)
```

I was hoping others might have had similar issues or could provide some assistance. I searched the site and couldn't find anything on the `t1way()` function.

Comment: It is better to show an example that reproduce the error/NA in the output.

Comment: I don't have a good example as the file is massive. I scraped 5 years worth of NFL Combine data. I am trying to compare 40 times across position groups. This is the error I get when running the post hoc test: Error in data.frame(psihat = c(" 0.73800", " 0.43766", " 0.14644", " 0.43915",  : 
  duplicate row.names: OG vs. NA, DT vs. NA, OT vs. NA, C vs. NA, QB vs. NA, OLB vs. NA, DE vs. NA, TE vs. NA, RB vs. NA, WR vs. NA, ILB vs. NA, FB vs. NA, CB vs. NA, FS vs. NA, SS vs. NA, NA vs. NA
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you have levels in your grouping variable that aren't represented in your sample.  For example, if you instead made your sample data with

```
Group <- factor(rep(c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3"), c(50,50,20)),
                levels=paste("Group", 1:4))
```

you would reproduce the error.  In your code, try with `droplevels`

```
t1way(Score ~ Group, data = droplevels(df), tr = 0.2)
```

The function `t1way` could be fixed to deal with this by changing the `split` to include the option `drop=TRUE`.